# How can i define a new function at runtime in c?

Tags: c, function

In c you can copy the code as a block of memory, so I was wondering if it was done by some developers or otherwise sensible and safe to copy the code of a function into a block allocated in the heap, change the code of the function in the heap, and then (mprotect ...) perform the "copied and modified" function, and what might be the consequences of leaving heap blocks executable from a security point of view. Or is there a way to run code defined at runtime in c?

```
void* handler(void* arg1, void* arg2, void* arg3) {
    typedef void* (*function)(void*, void*, void*, void*);
    return ((function)FUNCTION_ADDRESS_TO_REPLACE)(SELF_ADDRESS_TO_REPLACE,
                                                   arg1,
                                                   arg2,
                                                   arg3);
}


void* allocate_new_function(void* function, void* self) {
    void* (*fun) () = 0;
    uint64_t size = (uint64_t) &allocate_new_function - (uint64_t) &handler; //48 byte
    fun = malloc(size);
    memcpy(fun, handler, size);
    replace(fun, size, SELF_ADDRESS_TO_REPLACE, self);
    replace(fun, size, FUNCTION_ADDRESS_TO_REPLACE, function);
    char *to_mprotect = (char*) (((uint64_t) fun / PAGE_SIZE) * PAGE_SIZE);
    uint64_t offset = (uint64_t) fun % PAGE_SIZE;
    if (offset + size > PAGE_SIZE) {
        mprotect(to_mprotect,
                 PAGE_SIZE,
                 PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE);
        mprotect(to_mprotect + PAGE_SIZE,
                 PAGE_SIZE,
                 PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE);
    } else {
        mprotect(to_mprotect,
                 PAGE_SIZE,
                 PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE);
    }
    return fun;
}
```

Here the allocated_function will execute the function "function" with implicit parameter self. Is there a better way to do this, or this method could be valid?

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: `mprotect` is not guaranteed to work with memory not obtained via `mmap`. So you'd better allocate the memory via `mmap` call, rather than `new`.

Comment: You are also relying on a specific ordering of functions in the generated object file, but there is nothing which guarantees you this. Functions can appear in any order compiler or linker chooses, so you approach on extracting the size of the function is deeply flawed.

Comment: yes that's true, but offset must be a multiple of the page size so i would waste much memory if i call allocate_new_function many times and if the program crash the page will remained mapped

Comment: Yes I tried like this, but i could suppose a max_size for the function instead of calculate exactly the value, beacuse handler is really small, the replace function stops at the first special_address found

Comment: You have to have a dedicated page for your code block anyhow - otherwise you will be changing permissions for random memory. If you do not want to waste pages, you have to implement your own allocator, which requests memory via mmap and uses memory in the available page, until you run out. What you are doing can be done - after all, this is what any JIT-optimizer is doing - but it requires careful and thoughtful approach to be production-grade. As a proof of concept your code is fine.

Comment: Yes it would be long to write i suppose. Thank you